# How to add an empty keyframe to grease pencil object using python?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I've been trying to add an empty keyframe to a grease pencil object using `bpy.ops.gpencil.blank_frame_add` but I just can't make it work.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.gpencil_add(align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1), type='EMPTY')
bpy.ops.gpencil.blank_frame_add(all_layers=True)
```

When I use the context menu draw>animation>Insert Blank Keyframe it works as it should, I only can't get it to work using the script.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of error message do you have while trying to do so ? I bet it's because you're using bpy.ops (which is a bad habit) and you will need to override the context. You'd better go for avoiding the use of operators and look at object.data.layers[i].frames.new(frame_number)

Comment: Hi @Tomreggae , thanks for looking into it! There's no error whatsoever, that's what confuses me. Similar operators like `bpy.ops.gpencil.active_frame_delete()` in the same structure work just fine. I've heard the bad habit part already, but as I am very new to scripting in Blender I started simple and dirty. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to dig deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling an operator from script, you need to [override the context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context).
But calling operators (bpy.ops) with python is generally a bad idea and you should access data trough bpy.data instead.

Here is the way to add new keyframes, you should find a similar way for creating new object.

```
import bpy
object = bpy.context.object #picking an object (the active one ?)

gp_object = object.data  #accessing its data
for layer in gp_object.layers :
    layer.frames.new(bpy.context.scene.frame_current) #the new() function needs a frame_number attribute , in this case, the current frame.
```

Comment: My sincere thanks!! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Footnote:  Calling `bpy` operators is not _generally_ a bad idea, although you can find thousands of posts that say so.  It is a bad idea to call `bpy.ops` functions in a situation where it will affect performance or when there is a cleaner way to do it without the ops.  It is a _good_ idea to call `bpy.ops` when doing so does not create a performance issue and the alternatives result in more difficult to understand code.,